# lag when scrolling with fixed background-image in mobile

Tags: html, css

I wanna have the website with a fixed background-image(about 46k) which works on my PC browser.

However, when scrolling on my mobile browser, it lays about one second to redraw the background-image.

Any ideas to solve this? Thanks

Here is my css:

```
html, body {
    background: url('/assets/img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a smooth fixed background on mobile using the **skrollr library** ([demo page that works on mobile](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/)).

(It's a known issue that fixed positioned elements do not work well across all popular mobile devices yet. [See this table of which devices support fixed positioning](http://caniuse.com/css-fixed).)

Comment: Thanks for reply. It seems i need to change my implement