# Skrollr mobile browser issue

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, skrollr

I'm trying to use skrollr to work around the [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680889/lag-when-scrolling-with-fixed-background-image-in-mobile) with CSS fixed background images in mobile browsers. I've built a stripped down version of my document schema with one background image and skrollr, here: http://lkoren.github.io/2013/10/16/skrollrTest.html

The file structure is

```
<body>
    <div class="doc-container" id="skrollr-body" >
        <div class="content-container" data-start="background-position: right 0px;" data-end="background-position: right 0px;">
            <div class = "info-box">
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
<Skrollr script goes here>
</body>
```

On my 2013 Nexus7 skrollr has no effect on Opera and Chrome. In FireFox it tends to cause a lot of sticking and stuttering.

In desktop FireFox and Chrome it works fine. I verified it's actually doing something by setting

```
data-end="background-position: right 500px;"
```

and getting the parallax effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the background-image to an element **outside of `#skrollr-body`** (e.g. `body`) . Because skrollr translates the `#skrollr-body` using CSS transforms, which moves your background as well.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'm starting to dig into the source to understand things, but in the meantime I've been trying a few options. The one that gets closest is setting 

    <div class = "info-box" id="skrollr-body"> and placing the header divs above the doc-container div. This creates two issues: 1) header elements get treated like they have had position: fixed set and 2) performance in firefox mobile is still really choppy (lots of long delays.)